# Return an encrypted string to place inside form variable

Tags: ios, encryption

So I am using RNEncryptor. Seems to work just great. My problem is that my form variable that I send to the server needs to be a string format. I have tried using: `[[NSString alloc] initWithData:encryptedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];` and I get a nil response. I'm not understanding why this nil response is occurring. **Note:** I don't care to decrypt the string. I just need the encrypted message to be placed inside of a string. Here's my code:

```
  NSError *error;
             NSData * data = [localQuery dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];  
         NSData*   encryptedData = [RNEncryptor encryptData:data
                                                withSettings:kRNCryptorAES256Settings
                                                    password:key
                                                       error:&error];
            //Returning nil response 
          NSString *   encryptedQuery = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:encryptedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Hopefully I am clear for everyone to understand. Thanks!

Comment: What are the values of `localQuery`, `data` and `encryptedData` prior to seeing `encryptedQuery == nil`?

Comment: There is essentially no such thing as an "encrypted string", if you take "string" to mean a C-type character string.  Encrypted data is inherently "binary" (uses all 8 bits of the byte) and must be further encoded via Base64 or some such if you wish to send it as character data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a nil response because not all data is an: NSUTF8StringEncoding` encoding.

If you need a string then convert the data to a Base64 string, that is how your problem is generally solved.

Instead of:

```
NSString *encryptedQuery = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:encryptedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Base64 encode the data:

```
NSString *encryptedQuery = [encryptedData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
```